# How to implement a vertical slide controller in a height limited div with many objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm nearly 2 months old in studying HTML, JavaScript and jQuery.  I've done a few things but never figured out how to implement a DIV (or anything you may suggest) to emulate a viewport which would display text, textarea, buttons, anchors etc all of which simply cannot fit or be seen within the size of the viewport.  Therefore the use of the vertical scroll.  No need for horizontal scrolling, though.  I can format the objects not to exceed the horizontal view.  I thought of using a div inside another div, but the objects inside the INNER DIV just bleed through and show up on the bottom of the site!

Is there some magical panel in jQuery created for that purpose?

TIA

Dennis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a containing div such as `<div id="container">`, you can add the following properties to it to get it's content to scroll vertically:

```
div#container {
    overflow-y: auto;
    height: 100px;
}
```

This CSS will show a vertical scroll bar *if* the div's content exceeds it's height. The only caveat with this solution is you *must* set a height on the div.

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/jamwaffles/7EMPL/).

Comment: Wow, I did not think it would be that easy!  Thank you!!

Comment: Not a problem. It's a wonderful relief when something's actually easier than you thought, not harder!